# Apache mod_rewrite works in .htaccess but not httpd.conf

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, httpd.conf

I'm experimenting with mod_rewrite for the first time (I'm a web newbie, but trying to learn).  I'm trying to get **bob.html** to redirect to **alice.html**  (read: URL stays the same, page content is **alice.html**).  Both files are in **/var/www/**.  I'm running Ubuntu 10.10 w/Apache 2.2.16.

Here's what works in the **.htaccess** file placed in the **/var/www/** directory:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^bob.html$ alice.html
</IfModule>
```

This behaves as expected, but it does not work when moved to the httpd.conf file (just learning best practices w/performance and such).  I read somewhere that when using mod_rewrite in **httpd.conf** file, leading slashes are required, so my **httpd.conf** file looks like:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/bob.html$ /alice.html
</IfModule>
```

I also read that **/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default** needs to have **AllowOverride** set to **All**.

```
<Directory /var/www> 
...
AllowOverride All
...
</Directory>
```

I *think* that's just for use with **.htaccess** but I wasn't sure so I just left it in.

With all of these configuration settings, the redirection does not work.  I've tested to make sure the file itself is being read (someone suggested **httpd.conf** isn't used anymore and **apache2.conf** is used instead) by inserting erroneous code.  I've taken a look at a couple other questions/answers but I still cant figure it out.

*Edit*: It should be noted that I'm using **/etc/init.d/apache2 restart** after each change to **httpd.conf** to restart Apache and (hopefully) reload the configuration.

Comment: what happens without the leading slashes in the httpd.conf directives?

Comment: No change in behavior.  Still doesn't work and it doesn't appear anything different is happening.

Comment: Where in your httpd.conf file did you put the `<IfModule>` block?

Comment: The `<IfModule>` is the only text in the file.

Answer (score 2):

Try wrapping the rewriterules in your httpd.conf file in <Location /></Location> tags. The seems to alter the behavior making it more similar to the .htaccess file.

Comment: Wrapping in <Location> tab made similar stuff work in .conf files that was working in .htaccess but not in .conf files before.